# Unable to merge unallocated space on the same drive

Tags: partitioning, gparted, disk, ext4

I'm trying to merge to old partitions into one which will result 2.75TB. I tried using the default disk utility in Ubuntu 20.04 but can't seem to make one partition. I also tried Gparted but same result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It seems like only unallocated space next to each other can be merged. As seen in the image their are 2 partitions in between and thus it cannot be merged.

Comment: Empty space is not a partition ;-)

Comment: It makes no sense to "merge unallocated space". You can move partitions a way that it is "merged".